# Azure Web services security checklist

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Is there any kind of security checklist for commonly used Azure Web Services i.e. Websites, Storage, Databases etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, everything can be found on the [main documentation hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/). Every service has its own documentation hub which contains the Security branch. For example, Web Apps - the security guidance on how to secure the Web App, is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-security/). And here is the [list of security points](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-security-readme/).

SQL Database - [security guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security-guidelines/). Did not see any guidances in format of checklist. The same for Storage - there is the [great security guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-security-guide/).

Comment: Thanku very much. That's what I was looking for.
Thanks again. :)

Comment: Awesome! If you see that as an answer, please mark your question as answer for a future use.